# Don't auto-close dialog onClick

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

How can I prevent the jQuery dialog from closing when I click the mouse?
Closing on hitting esc is fine but I want to keep it open until I close it by clicking the close-icon.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dialogbeforeclose` event to pass a callback function that will be called whenever the dialog is about to close.

If you return `false` from this function, the close will be cancelled.

```
$('.selector').bind('dialogbeforeclose', function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#event-beforeclose

You can do something like check the element that the event was fired from, and use that to determine whether or not the user clicked on the X to close or on something else.